# Is it possible to define a nameless function that returns an interface?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand some Go code online.

```
var botInterface func(*Server) eintefaces.BotInterface

func SetBotInterface(b func(*Server) einterface.BotInterface){
   botInterface = b 
}
```

Does anyone know what the code is saying? There is no implementation of the nameless function. From what I can tell is that botInterface is defined as a function that returns a interface. Currently botInterface is nil and that is the only related code.

Answer (score 6):

`func(*Server) eintefaces.BotInterface` is not a nameless function, it's a [function type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types). It's the type of a function that takes `*Server` as its argument and returns a value of type `eintefaces.BotInterface`.

`botInterface` is an unexported variable. Its type is a function type described above.

The `SetBotInterface()` exported function gives the possibility to set (assign) a value to the unexported `botInterface` variable. You have to pass a function value of the same type, and it simply assigns it to the unexported variable (you can't access the unexported variable otherwise).

See a similar example with usage:

```
var f func(string) io.Writer

func SetF(v func(string) io.Writer) {
    f = v
}

func exampleF(s string) io.Writer {
    fmt.Println("Received:", s)
    return os.Stdout
}

func main() {
    SetF(exampleF)

    w := f("foo")
    w.Write([]byte("bar"))
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lPoD1Fvc7rL)):

```
Received: foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not anonymous function but function type. This code allows you to assign your own function to an unexported `botInterface` variable (which you can't directly change from outside) in that package. You pass any function that takes `*Server` and returns `einterface.BotInterface` as an argument to `SetBotInterface`. Argument is then set to `botInterface` and probably called somewhere in that package.

So somewhere in your package you can do

```golang
func MyFunc(s *thatpackage.Server) einterface.BotInterface {
 // your code here...
}
```

and then later pass it to that package like this:

```golang
thatpackage.SetBotInterface(MyFunc)

// or even passing anonymous function directly:
thatpackage.SetBotInterface(func (s *thatpackage.Server) einterface.BotInterface {
  // your code here...
})
```

Note: I referred to package containing SetBotInterface as `thatpackage` because name is not known from your question.

This approach is often used to implement various customizable handlers in frameworks, etc.

You can think of code you posted like this - it makes it easier to understand what happens there:

```golang
type BotInterfaceFuncType = func(*Server) eintefaces.BotInterface 

var botInterface BotInterfaceFuncType

func SetBotInterface(b BotInterfaceFuncType){
   botInterface = b 
}
```